# Game over screen showing up at the wrong times

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make it so when the white cube hits the red ones it will show a game over screen but sometimes the game over screen flashes when it's not supposed to.

I expected for the game over to show when the white cube hits a red one.

the game is red squares spawn on top of the screen and fall down and you the white square are trying to avoid it

```
import pygame
import random

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the screen size
screen_width = 640
screen_height = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

# Set the background color
background_color = (0, 0, 0)
screen.fill(background_color)

# Set the character size and position
character_size = 50
character_x = screen_width / 2 - character_size / 2
character_y = screen_height / 2 - character_size / 2

# Set the character movement speed
move_speed = 5

# Set the enemy size and speed
enemy_size = 30
enemy_speed = 3

# Set the list of enemies
enemies = []

# Set the font for the game over screen
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 48)

# Set the clock to limit the framerate
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Game loop
running = True
game_over = False
while running:
    # Handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    if not game_over:
        # Handle key presses
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            character_x -= move_speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            character_x += move_speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            character_y -= move_speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            character_y += move_speed

        # Fill the screen with the background color
        screen.fill(background_color)

        # Draw the character
        white_color = (255, 255, 255)
        character_rect = pygame.Rect(character_x, character_y, character_size, character_size)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white_color, character_rect)

        # Draw a border around the character
        border_color = (0, 0, 0)
        border_thickness = 2
        border_rect = character_rect.inflate(border_thickness * 2, border_thickness * 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, border_color, border_rect, border_thickness)

        # Spawn new enemies randomly at the top of the screen
        if random.random() < 0.05:
            # Set the enemy position randomly at the top of the screen
            enemy_x = random.randint(0, screen_width - enemy_size)
            enemy_y = 0

            # Add the enemy to the list of enemies
            enemies.append(pygame.Rect(enemy_x, enemy_y, enemy_size, enemy_size))

        # Move the enemies and check for collisions with the character
        for enemy in enemies:
            # Move the enemy
            enemy.move_ip(0, enemy_speed)

            # Draw the enemy
            red_color = (255, 0, 0)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, red_color, enemy)

            # Check for collisions with the character
            if enemy.colliderect(character_rect):
                game_over = True

        # Remove enemies that have gone off the bottom of the screen
        enemies = [enemy for enemy in enemies if enemy.top < screen_height]

        # Update the screen
        pygame.display.update()

        # Limit the framerate to 60 FPS
        clock.tick(60)
    else:
        # Fill the screen with the background color
        screen.fill(background_color)

        # Display the game over message


    # Display the game over message
    game_over_message = font.render("Game Over", True, (255, 255, 255))
    message_rect = game_over_message.get_rect(center=(screen_width/2, screen_height/2))
    screen.blit(game_over_message, message_rect)

    # Update the screen
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You have typed it in the main loop

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation). Draw either the game scene or the end of game screen. Draw the gam over screen only in case of `game_over` is `True`. Updating the display and limiting the frames per second after drawing one of the scenes:

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    if not game_over:

        # [...]

        # DELETE
        # pygame.display.update()
        # DELTE
        # clock.tick(60)

    else:
        # Fill the screen with the background color
        screen.fill(background_color)

    # INDENTATION
    #-->|

        # Display the game over message
        game_over_message = font.render("Game Over", True, (255, 255, 255))
        message_rect = game_over_message.get_rect(center=(screen_width/2, screen_height/2))
        screen.blit(game_over_message, message_rect)

    # Update the screen
    pygame.display.update()

    # Limit the framerate to 60 FPS
    clock.tick(60)
```